# Keras/Conv2D: Strange, I use padding=SAME, but the size is still reduced

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I set padding to SAME or same, but the output is still being reduced, what's wrong then?
, as I understand according to the official doc, the output size shall be the same to the input one, do I forget what is important?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.keras.Input([120, 120, 3])

conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME")(x)
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME")(conv)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[conv])

model.summary()

image_batch = tf.random.normal(shape=[10, 120, 120, 3])
y_pred = model(image_batch)
print(y_pred.shape)
```

Output

```py
odel: "model_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)         [(None, 120, 120, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 60, 60, 3)         84        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 30, 3)         84        
=================================================================
Total params: 168
Trainable params: 168
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
(10, 30, 30, 3)
```

Comment: Yes, you forgot about the strides.

Comment: @NanoBit Why not? it looks correct, it is giving the input to the first conv layer.

Comment: @NanoBit What you wrote made no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `strides=(2, 2)`. It skips a step during the convolution operation and so reduces the h & w by a factor of 2 at each convolutional layer.
[image]

If you set `strides=(1, 1)` it gives the same output shape.

Comment: thank you @Nicolas Gervais and which means that the padding="same" is inconsistent, at least it is not the "same" what the describes? Or do I miss some notices from the official document?

Comment: "valid" means no padding. "same" results in padding with zeros evenly to the left/right or up/down of the input such that output has the same height/width dimension as the input.

Comment: `padding="SAME"` won't correct for the effect of strides